# Why my AutoComplete control is not call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor, autocomplete

I've followed this [tutorial](http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/auto-complete-in-razor-mvc-with-jquery-and-linq-to-entities/)...

My Controller's method "Name" is never call...

Here is the code:

**View**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("Name", "Reservation")', { minChars: 3   });//Never call... When I put a simple alert, it works !
});
</script>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Name)

</div>
```

**Controller method**

```
public ActionResult Name(string q)
{
        var customers = (from c in db.Customers where c.Name.Contains(q) select c.Name).Distinct().Take(10);
        string content = string.Join<string>("\n", customers);
        return Content(content);
}
```

I'm lost... Can you help me to find what I'm doing wrong please ? Thanks in advance...

Finally he reaches my controller's method ! But He never display the list corresponding to the input text :(

**Update 16:04**

[image]

Comment: Finally he reaches my controller's method ! But He never display the list corresponding to the input text :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID for the input generated by:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
```

Won't just be `Name`, it will be `Customer_Name`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Customer_Name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("Name", "Reservation")', { minChars: 3   });//Never call... When I put a simple alert, it works !
});
```

---

There seems to be some confusion here, the tutorial you're following uses jQuery Autocomplete but you appear to be using jQuery UI autocomplete. Both are slightly different, using the default options:

### jQuery-UI Autocomplete

(http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Customer_Name").autocomplete({ source: '@Url.Action("Name", "Reservation")', minLength: 3 });
    });
</script>

public ActionResult Name(string term)
{
    var customers = ...get a list of customer names filtered by term
    return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### jQuery Autocomplete

(https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Customer_Name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("Name", "Reservation")', { minChars: 3 });
    });
</script>

public ActionResult Name(string q)
{
    var customers = ...get a list of customer names filtered by q
    return Content(string.Join("\n", customers));
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Finally he reaches my controller's method ! But He never display the list corresponding to the input text :(

Comment: Does your customer query definitely return at least one name (and are you typing > 2 characters in to the input box)?

Comment: My query is null because "string q" is null ! He don't get the input text :(

Comment: Which version of jQuery and jQuery autocomplete are you using? Using the latest versions (jQuery 1.7.1, [jQuery autocomplete master](https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete)) I tried it out and `q` was set correctly.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? If it's Firefox open the web console (cmd/ctrl + shift + k) to check which URL is being requested when you type text into the box.

Comment: Url Requested (when I type "Ada" for example): http://localhost:4987/Reservation/Name?term=ada

Comment: Ah, ok. Change `public ActionResult Name(string q)` to `public ActionResult Name(string term)`

Comment: Thank you, When I type "ada", I get the user's name like this into the console... But I never get the dynamic list under my editor... I will upload a picture in my first post...

Comment: Thank you so much ! You're right... I have downloaded the "ui-autocomplete" and used the "autocomplete" method...